# Days Since Last Help Ticket was Filed

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, domo

I am trying to create a report to show me the last date a customer filed a ticket.

Customers can file dozens of tickets.  I want to know when the last ticket was filed and show how many days it's been since they have done so.

The fields I have are:

Customer,

Ticket_id,

Date_Closed

All from the Same table  "Tickets"

I'm thinking I want to do a ranking of tickets by min date?  I tried this query to grab something but it's giving me all the tickets from the customer.  (I'm using SQL in a product called Domo)

```
select * from (select *, rank() over (partition by "Ticket_id" 
                order by "Date_Closed" desc) as date_order
from tickets ) zd
where date_order = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Customer, datediff(day, date_closed, current_date) as days_since_last_tkt
from 
(select *, rank() over (partition by Customer order by "Date_Closed" desc) as date_order
from tickets) zd
join tickets t on zd.date_closed = t.date_closed
where zd.date_order = 1
```

Or you can simply do

```
select customer, datediff(day, max(Date_closed), current_date) as days_since_last_tkt
from tickets
group by customer
```

To select other fields

```
select t.* 
from tickets t
join (select customer, max(Date_closed) as mxdate,
      datediff(day, max(Date_closed), current_date) as days_since_last_tkt
      from tickets
      group by customer) tt 
on t.customer = tt.customer and tt.mxdate = t.date_closed
```

Comment: So I think I like this and will try it.  I want to avoid the "max" function since you have to do a group by for all the fields in the select statement.  I have a ton of fields I want to bring in so I can analyze the data further.

Comment: If you need other fields, include this as a sub-query and `join` it to the original table.

Comment: ah, ok that makes sense.  I'll pull in the ticket id and join it by that.  I'm working with Domo so it's not typical SQL Studio.  But this is very helpful

Comment: shouldn't I join on the ticket id instead of the "customer"?

Answer (score 2):

This should be simple enough,

```
  SELECT customer,
     MAX (date_closed) last_date,
   ROUND((SYSDATE - MAX (date_closed)),0) days_since_last_ticket_logged
    FROM emp
GROUP BY customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a simple sub-query to select the last closed date for the customer. Then compare this to today with `datediff()` to get the number of days since last closed.

```
Select 
LastTicket.Customer,
LastTicket.LastClosedDate,
DateDiff(day,LastTicket.LastClosedDate,getdate()) as DaysSinceLastClosed

From    
(select
tickets.customer
max(tickets.dateClosed) as LastClosedDate
from tickets
Group By tickets.Customer) as LastTicket
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses this is what I did:

```
select "Customer",
Max("date_closed") "last_date,

round(datediff(DAY, CURRENT_DATE, max("date_closed")), 0) as "Closed_date"

from tickets

group by "Customer"
ORDER BY "Customer"
```